# Run function before dispatch action in mapDispatchToProps in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Im my container I would like to make a treatment before dispatch an Action

So first I declared a function

```
const resumeCallReq = async (call) => {
    const body = { id: call.callId }
    const resCallRes = await resumeCall('queueBaseUrl', body);
    return dispatch(resume(call))
}
```

Then call it in `mapDispatchToProps`

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    pauseCall: (call) => pauseCallReq(call),
    resumeCall: (call) => resumeCallReq(call),
    endCall: (call) => dispatch(end(call)),
    addNote: (call) => dispatch(addNote(call))
})
```

I get error

```
'dispatch' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dispatch` not defined within `resumeCallReq` scope.

There are plenty of ways to get `dispatch` into scope, one of them is curried function:

```
const resumeCallReq = (dispatch) => async (call) => {
  const body = { id: call.callId };
  const resCallRes = await resumeCall("queueBaseUrl", body);
  return dispatch(resume(call));
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  resumeCall: (call) => resumeCallReq(dispatch)(call),
});
```

Or you can just define the function within `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  const resumeCallReq = async (call) => {
    const body = { id: call.callId };
    const resCallRes = await resumeCall("queueBaseUrl", body);
    return dispatch(resume(call));
  };

  return {
    pauseCall: (call) => pauseCallReq(call),
    resumeCall: (call) => resumeCallReq(call),
    endCall: (call) => dispatch(end(call)),
    addNote: (call) => dispatch(addNote(call)),
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass `dispatch` as argument to `resumeCallReq`

```js
const resumeCallReq = async (call, dispatch) => {
    const body = { id: call.callId }
    const resCallRes = await resumeCall('queueBaseUrl', body);
    return dispatch(resume(call))
}
```

and in `mapDispatchToProps`

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    pauseCall: (call) => pauseCallReq(call),
    resumeCall: (call) => resumeCallReq(call, dispatch),
    endCall: (call) => dispatch(end(call)),
    addNote: (call) => dispatch(addNote(call))
})
```